# How to modify small part of XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML file with some 25 elements. I just want to transform 2 elements and retain the remaining XML. Could somebody tell me how to do. All examples online are modifying xml doc as whole, I dont want this. I just want to modify values of two elements.

Comment: How are these two elements uniquely identified?, post a sample of the xml.

Comment: Post a sample XML, and what you want those 2 elements transformed into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A practical example below, where I parse an xsd file and remove all the annotations from it.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- copy all nodes and attributes -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- but remove annotations -->
<xsl:template match="xs:annotation"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Such tasks are solved by using the identity transformation template which is

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then by adding templates for the elements to be changed e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <bar>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </bar>
</xsl:template>
```

changes `foo` to `bar` elements and/or

```
<xsl:template match="foobar"/>
```

deletes `foobar` elements.

To give you a further example, for instance if we want to copy `baz` elements with their content but want to add a `new` element we can add a template

```
<xsl:template match="baz">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <new>...</new>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

As long as you keep the identity transformation alive (with apply-templates) for anything you don't want to be changed you can pretty well structure your stylesheet by writing a template for each element to be changed.